# Determining the matrix of a projection.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $f$ be an endomorphism of $\mathbb{R^3}$ which the matrix in the standard basis is $A=\begin{bmatrix}3&2&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Let $F_1=Ker(f-Id_\mathbb{R^3})$ , $F_2=Ker(f-2Id_\mathbb{R^3})$

Let $p$ be the projection on $F_1$ parallel to $F_2$

Determine the matrix of the projection $p$.

Method 1:

$\mathbb{R^3}=F_1 \oplus F_2$

$\forall v \in \mathbb{R^3} , v=v_1+v_2 $ with $v_1 \in F_1 , v_2 \in F_2$

$f(v)=f(v_1)+f(v_2)$

($f-Id)(v_1)=0$

Thus:

$f(v_1)=v_1$

$(f-2Id)(v_2)=0$

Thus

$f(v_2) = 2v_2$

$f(v)=v_1+2v_2=p(v)+2(v-v_1)=p(v)+2(Id(v)-p(v))=2Id(v)-p(v)$

This leads to : $p(v)=2Id(v)-f(v)$

And the matrix of $p$ is $P=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}3&2&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&0\\1&2&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

Method 2:

$p$ is the projection on $F_1$ parallel to $F_2$ hence $F_2$ is in the kernel of $p$

$F_1=span${$v_1=(1-1,0),v_2=(0,0,1)$}

$F_2=span${$v_3=(-2,1,0)$}

Let's determine $p$ in the basis $B=${$v_1,v_2,v_3$}

We have $p(v_3)=0$ , $p(v_1)=v_1$ ($v_1 \in F_1$) , $p(v_2)=v_2$ ($v_2 \in F_1$)

Hence the matrix of $p$ in the basis B is $P_B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

The transition matrix from $B$ to the standard basis is $T=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&0\\0&0&1\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$,$T^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2\\-1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$

And the matrix of $p$ in the standard basis would be equal to :

$P$=$T . P_B . T^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&0\\0&0&1\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix} . \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} . \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2\\-1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

How come both of these methods give out different solutions ?

Where did i go wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you've mixed up your transition matrices. Remember, you're only supposed to multiply $P_B$ by coordinate column vectors with respect to $B$. What you've written as $T^{-1}$ takes column vectors with respect to $B$ and produces the same vector as a column vector with respect to the standard basis. That is, $T^{-1} v$ is a standard basis coordinate column vector, not with respect to $B$. If you multiply the other way,
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2\\-1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&0\\0&0&1\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&0\\1&2&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix},$$
as required.

Comment: It seems like I'm a bit confused about the whole transition matrix thing , If $T^{-1}$ is a transition matrix from the standard basis to $B$ shouldn't $T^{-1} . v_s=v_B$?Thanks

Comment: And doesn’t $T^{-1}$ take column vectors with respect to the standard basis and produces the same vector as a column vector with respect to $B$?

Comment: Both of these things are true. If we let $M$ be the middle matrix, we have $$TMT^{-1}[v]_S = TM[v]_B = T[P_{F_1,F_2}(v)]_B = [P_{F_1,F_2}(v)]_S$$

Comment: If this is true $TMT^{-1}[v]_S = TM[v]_B = T[P_{F_1,F_2}(v)]_B = [P_{F_1,F_2}(v)]_S$ then why isn't $P$ equal to $TMT^{-1}$ I've drawn the diagram http://prntscr.com/hx5qc2

Comment: Ugh, I hate this notation. I think I've gotten myself backwards. My multiplication above is actually $T^{-1}MT$, according to $T$ as defined above. So, in my above comment, replace $T$ with $T^{-1}$. $$$$ $T^{-1}$ is defined by taking the vectors of $B$ and putting them as columns in a matrix. This means a coordinate vector with respect to $B$ is converted to $S$. $T$, its inverse, therefore converts from $S$ to $B$. That is the first vector that should interact with the vector, and hence be the rightmost multiple. $$ $$ Your diagram just has $T$ and $T^{-1}$ backwards.

Comment: $T=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&0\\0&0&1\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$,

$\begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&0\\0&0&1\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix} . \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$
,

$\begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&0\\0&0&1\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix} . \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$
,
$\begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&0\\0&0&1\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix} . \begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

$T$ converts $v_1$into $e_1$ , $v_2$ into $e_2$ and $v_3$ into $e_3$ , doesn't that mean it converted vectors in $B$ into vectors in $S$?

Comment: No, quite the opposite. The vector $[1, -1, 0]^T$ is a standard basis coordinate vector, and indeed the first one in $B$. We can convert this vector to a coordinate vector in $B$ by expressing $$(1, -1, 0) = 1v_1 + 0v_2 + 0v_3,$$ which produces the coordinate column vector in terms of $B$, $[1, 0, 0]^T$.

Comment: It's confusion like this that makes me prefer basis-free linear algebra. You're taking a single vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If $e_1, e_2, e_3$ is the standard basis, then it can be expressed by $1e_1 - 1e_2 + 0e_3$. In terms of $B$, it is $1v_1 + 0v_2 + 0v_3$. Both these linear combinations produce the same element, call it $w$, of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, $[w]_S = [1, -1, 0]^T$, but $[w]_B = [1, 0, 0]^T$. Since $T[w]_S = [w]_B$, this supports the fact that $T$ changes from standard basis $S$ to $B$.

Comment: Thanks that made things a lot clearer.